# Scaling an image that is the background of a button

Tags: android, image, button

I have quite a big button and I'd like to set an image as a background for it. I'd like it to be somethig like 70% of the button space, with the gravity in the middle.

Comment: Are you talking about Android or web proramming?

Answer (score 3):

The "good" way of doing that is to use a 9-Patch image:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html

There's a tool available for that:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

If you want to use your own image, then the button will be automatically resized to the size of the image.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QMgHJ.png I have six buttons stick each other, so 9-patch isnt good solution for me. I'd like to have about 70% button's space covering because it sould look like a menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
style="background:url('yourimage') no-repeat; background-size:70%; background-position:50% 50%;"
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me I suppose it's code for java language I need one for Adnroid

Comment: That's web programming (css style), I suppose this answer was added before you added details in the question